# quick tiles is shown but not active in notification bar

Tags: android

I am trying to implement simple quick settings tile with the help of google docs,

but my tile appears to be there but greyed out(intent activity)- I can't click or do anything with it and cant remove it either without restarting my phone(one plus 3T/oreo8.0.0).

and the same thing goes with sample code google provided.

what things do i need to keep in mind/ how to do it?

is there anything I am missing?

I saw one similar question but it was a bit over my head.

MANIFEST

```
 <application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".QSIntentService"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp"
        android:label="@string/qs_intent_tile_label"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_QUICK_SETTINGS_TILE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.quicksettings.action.QS_TILE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name=".ResultActivity"
        android:label="@string/result_label"/>


</application>
```

JAVA (Main ACtivity)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

}

QSintentservice.java

```
public class QSIntentService extends TileService{

private static final String SERVICE_STATUS_FLAG = "serviceStatus";
private static final String PREFERENCES_KEY = "com.google.android_quick_settings";

@Override
public void onClick() {

    updateTile();

    boolean isCurrentlyLocked = this.isLocked();

    if (!isCurrentlyLocked) {

        Resources resources = getApplication().getResources();

        Tile tile = getQsTile();
        String tileLabel = tile.getLabel().toString();
        String tileState = (tile.getState() == Tile.STATE_ACTIVE) ?
                resources.getString(R.string.service_active) :
                resources.getString(R.string.service_inactive);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                ResultActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra(ResultActivity.RESULT_ACTIVITY_NAME_KEY,
                tileLabel);
        intent.putExtra(ResultActivity.RESULT_ACTIVITY_INFO_KEY,
                tileState);

        startActivityAndCollapse(intent);
    }

}

private void updateTile() {

    Tile tile = this.getQsTile();
    boolean isActive = getServiceStatus();

    Icon newIcon;
    String newLabel;
    int newState;

    if (isActive) {

        newLabel = String.format(Locale.US,
                "%s %s",
                getString(R.string.tile_label),
                getString(R.string.service_active));

        newIcon = Icon.createWithResource(getApplicationContext(), ic_android_black_24dp);

        newState = Tile.STATE_ACTIVE;

    } else {
        newLabel = String.format(Locale.US,
                "%s %s",
                getString(R.string.tile_label),
                getString(R.string.service_inactive));

        newIcon =
                Icon.createWithResource(getApplicationContext(),
                        android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);

        newState = Tile.STATE_INACTIVE;
    }

    tile.setLabel(newLabel);
    tile.setIcon(newIcon);
    tile.setState(newState);

    tile.updateTile();
}

private boolean getServiceStatus() {

    SharedPreferences prefs =
            getApplicationContext()
                    .getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_KEY,
                            MODE_PRIVATE);

    boolean isActive = prefs.getBoolean(SERVICE_STATUS_FLAG, false);
    isActive = !isActive;

    prefs.edit().putBoolean(SERVICE_STATUS_FLAG, isActive).apply();

    return isActive;
}
```

}

Result.java

```
public class ResultActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String RESULT_ACTIVITY_INFO_KEY = "resultActivityInfo";
public static final String RESULT_ACTIVITY_NAME_KEY = "resultActivityName";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

    if (getIntent() != null) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        assert extras != null;
        String tileState = extras.getString(RESULT_ACTIVITY_INFO_KEY);
        String tileName = extras.getString(RESULT_ACTIVITY_NAME_KEY);

        TextView outputText = findViewById(R.id.result_info);
        outputText.setText(String.format(Locale.US,
                getString(R.string.result_output),
                tileName,
                tileState));

        TextView returnHome = findViewById(R.id.result_return_main);
        returnHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent goHome = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MainActivity.class);

                startActivity(goHome);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what have you tried so far. Can you show us the code ?

Comment: i have updated my question, please check

Comment: i guess extras you sending is the bundle is null.. can you put a breakpoint and check if its going there

Comment: also are you facing this only on one+ 3t ?? Because i tried your code in my emulator and device, it works fine

Comment: I don't have another phone for testing, so yes .. till now I have tested on 1+3T

Comment: Do try with emulator.. it does work

Comment: on ryzen CPU emulators do not work. :(

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine on other devices. However, there is an issue in one plus quick setting menu as its observed and brought to notice. Check the below link to verify,

https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/android-oreo-8-0-oxigenos-quick-settings-bug.690621/

[image]

Comment: the issue is the icon itself is 'grey/inactive' not in off state.